# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-multidex

**I have got error while debug app running**

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension
>   only for .CLASS files

**I have tried it but I got the same error every time.**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: first delete build folder form your project and clean project and rebuild . I resolved this issue by this way. Hope, this will work for you

Comment: @nihal_softyI have already tried it.

Comment: @nihal_softy When I generate build APK that time gets this error.

Comment: are  you trying to build apk on debug mode or app mode?

Comment: No I have generate Build->Buid APK(s)

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'  use this to make multidex in your project adn let me know issue is still there or not ?

Comment: If any changes in gradle file and then compile and run I get the same error but without any changes, I have generated debug apk then I have got Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write (Duplicate zip entry [79.jar:org/intellij/lang/annotations/Identifier.class]))

Answer (score 3):

Hi As per myUnderstanding, Follow this type build on your project

And change your local.properties with this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m




android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 7
    versionName "0.7"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

When i was cleaned my project this issue was solved.

[Clean Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZvik.png)